# How to get Unity showing reward video price or reward amount

Tags: android, ads, unityads

I am trying to show unity ads in android and its successfully showing real ads. But there is nothing I can see where I will get reward amount or showing video price.
Unity ad listener I have implemented,

```
private class UnityAdsListener implements IUnityAdsListener {

    @Override
    public void onUnityAdsReady(String s) {

        if(i == 0) {

            tvUnityAd.setText("Show ad: " + s);
        }

        /*if(UnityAds.isReady()){
            UnityAds.show(RewardVideoActivity.this);
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onUnityAdsStart(String s) {

        tvRewardVideoInfo.setText("unity: " + s);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUnityAdsFinish(String s, UnityAds.FinishState finishState) {

        tvUnityAd.setText("finish: " + s + ", " + finishState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUnityAdsError(UnityAds.UnityAdsError unityAdsError, String s) {

        tvUnityAd.setText("error: " + s);
    }
}
```

Here nothing is giving me that amount based on which I will reward users.
How I can come to know the minimum amount or amount of the showing ad?